# Rx Scala combine latest of multiple streams

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, observable, rx-java

I am in the process of learning reactive programming in scala.

I am at a place where I need to combine a set of streams into one. In short, I am combining inputs from a GUI style editor (color pickers etc) into one all-inclusive stream. For that I could use the combineLatest function of the observables.

The [Rx Java](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) Observable offers variants of combineLatest with as many inputs as necessary. [Rx Scala](http://rxscala.github.io/comparison.html) only offers for two, and for the rest there's only the unhelpful *"If C# doesn’t need it, Scala doesn’t need it either ;-)"*

So, my question is, what is a simple way of getting tuples of values from a set of observables every time an observable changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a static function in the [Observable](http://rxscala.github.io/scaladoc/rx/lang/scala/Observable$.html) object.
There is no default selector that produces a tuple. One has to write their own selector for combining the emitted values